# Convert JSON to List of Lists in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, numpy

Trying to implement python code to get JSON data to list of lists.

JSON DATA :

```
[{
            'service_count': 12,
            'service_name': 'jboss',
            'service_type': 'Application Server'
        },
        {
            'service_count': 18,
            'service_name': 'iis',
            'service_type': 'Application/Web Server'
        },
        {
            'service_count': 5,
            'service_name': 'mysql',
            'service_type': 'Database'
        },
        {
            'service_count': 9,
            'service_name': 'apache',
            'service_type': 'Web Server'
        }
    ]
```

Expected Output

```
service_type = ['Application Server', 'Application/Web Server', 'Database', 'Web Server']

service_name = ['jboss', 'iis', 'mysql', 'apache']

service_count = [[12,0,0,0],[0,18,0,0],[0,0,5,0],[0,0,0,9]]
```

Would appreciate if provided any inputs or suggestions to implement code to get the expected output from the JSON data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm trying to figure out how to implement code to get the Json data to split into three different lists assigned to variables and the service count should be list of lists with the values in mentioned format.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question; where's your *code*?

Comment: Is it okay to have a dictionary with associate with each key such as service_count': [12, 18, 5, 9],
                'service_name': ['jboss', 'iis', 'mysql', 'apache'], etc.

Comment: I don't see any json in this question. What you've pasted under JSON DATA just looks like a python string representation of a python dictionary. This is different than JSON

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
"I don't know how to code this" is too broad an issue for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python read JSON list", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are representing the JSON as a list of dicts called json:

```
service_count = numpy.diag([x.service_count for x in json])
service_type = [x.service_type for x in json]
service_name = [x.service_name for x in json]
```

Comment: thank for your reply.... can we use like key[0] instead of mentioning "x.service_count", to make it more dynamic...

Comment: Yes - you can use `json[0].keys()` to get a list of keys in the first dict in the list of dicts, but this is bad in practice, since you can't guarantee every dict will have the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd   

d = [{ 'service_count': 12, 'service_name': 'jboss', 'service_type': 'Application Server' }, 
     { 'service_count': 18, 'service_name': 'iis', 'service_type': 'Application/Web Server' }, 
     { 'service_count': 5, 'service_name': 'mysql', 'service_type': 'Database' }, 
     { 'service_count': 9, 'service_name': 'apache', 'service_type': 'Web Server' } ]

# read json into df
d = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d)

# set to categorical - to ensure correct sequence of values
d['service_count'] = pd.Categorical( d['service_count'], categories=d.service_count.tolist())

# convert data to dict
d_dict = d.to_dict('list')

# create one hot sequence of service_count variable
lst = (pd.get_dummies(d['service_count']).values * d['service_count'].values)

# convert array to list
d_dict['service_count'] = [list(x) for x in lst] 

print(d_dict)

{'service_count': [[12, 0, 0, 0], [0, 18, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 9]],
 'service_name': ['jboss', 'iis', 'mysql', 'apache'],
 'service_type': ['Application Server',
  'Application/Web Server',
  'Database',
  'Web Server']}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Really appreciate your help. One quick question. 

In the below code.. what is "service_ordered"... I tried to run the code but got an error with this keyword.

lst = (pd.get_dummies(d['service_ordered']).values * d['service_count'].values)